# Is there really no way to close the browser?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, blazor

I want to implement a close button to close the browser in the Blazer server-side app.

So I created a close button and called window.close() with javascript.

**_host.cshtml**

```
<body>
    <app>
        <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
    </app>

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        <environment include="Staging,Production">
            An error has occurred. This application may no longer respond until reloaded.
        </environment>
        <environment include="Development">
            An unhandled exception has occurred. See browser dev tools for details.
        </environment>
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>

    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
    <script>
        function winclose() {
            window.close();
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to make it possible to exit by typing in the password.
(i'm using Matblazor nuget package)

**MainLayout(razor)**

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

<div class="sidebar">
    <NavMenu />
</div>

<MatDialog @bind-IsOpen="@DialogIsOpen">
    <EditForm EditContext="EditContext" OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit">
        <DataAnnotationsValidator />
        <p>
            <MatTextField Style="margin:2px;" Label="Password" @bind- Value="passWordModel.PassWord" Type="password" />
            <ValidationMessage For="@(() => passWordModel.PassWord)" />
        </p>
        <MatButton Class="cancelbtn" Type="reset" @onclick="@CancelClicked">Cancel</MatButton>
        <MatButton Type="submit">OK</MatButton>
    </EditForm>
</MatDialog>

<div class="main">
    <div class="top-row px-4">
        <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/" target="_blank">About</a>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" @onclick="@ExitClicked">Close</button>
    </div>

    <div class="content px-4">
        @Body
    </div>
</div>
```

**MainLayout(code)**

```
@code{
    EditContext EditContext { get; set; }
    PassWordModel passWordModel = new PassWordModel();
        public bool DialogIsOpen { get; set; } = false;

    public class PassWordModel
    {
        [CustomValidation(typeof(PassWordModel), nameof(ValidatePassWord))]
        public string PassWord { get; set; }

        public static ValidationResult ValidatePassWord(string password, ValidationContext vc)
        {

            return string.Equals("1234", password)
                ? ValidationResult.Success
                : new ValidationResult("The password is not correct.", new[] { vc.MemberName 
});
        }
    }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        EditContext = new EditContext(passWordModel);
        base.OnInitialized();
    }

    void ExitClicked()
    {
        DialogIsOpen = true;
    }

    void CancelClicked()
    {
        passWordModel.PassWord = null;
        EditContext = new EditContext(passWordModel);

        DialogIsOpen = false;

    }

    private async void HandleValidSubmit()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("HandleValidSubmit!");

        try
        {
            await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("winclose");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

    }
}
```

I called window.close() but it doesn't work.

When I press f12 to check the developer tools, the following warning message appears.

'Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by them.'

As a result of googling, I came to the conclusion that I cannot close self window due to security issues.

If so, is there really no solution? Is it impossible at all?

Comment: correct, its my browser, you can't close it

Comment: "Hey user - your browser with all your tabs? Not there any more! Did you listen to music online? You don't now!"

Comment: Main question is why would you ever want to do this in the first place

Comment: There is no benefit for the user whatsoever. To close the browser entirely, they have that little "X" anyway. And that's just a single click without typing in passwords.